# How do I manually purge the error logs for NServiceBus

Tags: nservicebus

I recently inherited a software project that uses Particulars NServiceBus.  After doing some reading I found that error log could be viewed through the ServicePulse.  Going in I see about 2 years worth of accumulation.  I would like to purge those, but it appears that outside of archiving and letting the system just purge it after so many days there is no way to manually purge the files.

I have just upgraded ServiceControl to 3.2.3 and ServicePulse to 1.14.4.

Is there a way to manually purge without having to resort to waiting on the retention period?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you need to configure data retention and lower audit and error [retention periods](https://docs.particular.net/servicecontrol/creating-config-file#data-retention). These settings can be [modified later](https://docs.particular.net/servicecontrol/how-purge-expired-data) by launching ServiceControl Management and editing the configuration settings for the instance.

Comment: I have done that, but on one box we are talking about 300K+ worth of error messages.  I was hoping there would be a better way.  This is on a test server so I have some flexibility.

Comment: On a test box you could stop SC and delete the database.

Comment: if I delete the db how would the db get recreated?  Create a new instance?

Comment: SC will recreate it. A new instance will require a different name and queue to be specified for endpoints.

Comment: Playing around with this in my dev environment it looks like I dont have to create a new instance.  I renamed the current db folder and then restarted SC and it appears to have created a new DB folder. for the existing named instance.  So I am good I think.  Maybe add this in your answer so I can mark it.

Comment: Renaming is in essence deleting the folder 